# Flutter - How to control google map markers opacity

Tags: flutter, localization, gps, google-maps-flutter

I need to make some markers semi-transparent depending on position. Is there any way to control the marker opacity?

Answer (score 0):

Use the alpha property

```
static final Marker defaultMarker = Marker(
  markerId: MarkerId("0"),
  position: LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
  alpha: 0.5)
```